# How to set default encoding for imap_search?

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

Php functions imap_sort and imap_search have encoding parameter, its null by default, but if it’s set in code to null the error occupies:

Uncaught TypeError: imap_sort() expects parameter 6 to be string, null

code: `\imap_sort($resource, $sortCriteria, $descending ? 1 : 0, \SE_UID, $query, null);`

How to set default value for encoding exactly (So, I can't just remove this parameter) ?

Comment: Last param on http://php.net/imap_sort shows a string param, try `"NULL"` instead of `null`

Comment: @AaronW, thanks, I see, but with NULL and "NULL" I have different results of function call.